# Parsing a valid json string by serde will cause an error - "trailing characters"

Tags: json, ruby, rust, serde

I have a Rust library and Ruby project. I call a Rust function from Ruby via FFi.

There's a function in the Rust library that receives a string and converts it into json.

Ruby side:

```
my_json_raw_str = {
  network: {
    server_address: "my_server.com"
  }
}

res = send_it_to_rust(my_json_raw_str.to_json)
```

A function in Rust will throw an exception when parsing json string sent to it from Ruby.

An error returned from Rust:

```
Invalid parameters: trailing characters at line 1 column 47\nparams: [{\"network\":{\"server_address\":\"my_server.com\"}}\u0000]
```

Json is valid, isn't it?

`serde`, `serde_json` and `serde_derive` are used on Rust side.

How to fix the error and why is it caused?

Comment: What's the `\u0000` doing in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Json is valid, isn't it?

Your JSON is *not* valid, because your FFI layer is not correct: if you look at the error it's clearly telling you that there is a trailing NUL byte in your data, meaning when bridging between C and Rust you left the trailing NUL byte from the C string.